# I18n redirection issue in struts2 web application

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, internationalization, locale

In my application Locale is dynamically selected by user from login page and  I am saving selected locale in Cookie.

I am facing I18n related problem in case of redirection in my web application.

When I redirect a page by URL by appending current locale then my application language remains same as selected language(i.e working fine in this case), but when I redirect to next page by struts redirection defined in struts.xml file the locale changes to the default value(English in my case).

For example:

In case of- `<result name="success" type="redirect">` , locale changes to default one.

In case I remove `type=redirect` then its working fine but my form will be submitted two times.

So is there any way to append locale to struts redirection at runtime?

Here is one of my interceptor stack:

```xml
<interceptor-stack name="sessionValidateStack">
    <interceptor-ref name="auditTrail"></interceptor-ref>
    <interceptor-ref name="sessionCheck"></interceptor-ref>
    <interceptor-ref name="service">
        <param name="code">DG</param>
        <param name="interfaceType">WEB</param>
    </interceptor-ref>
    <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"></interceptor-ref>
    <interceptor-ref name="expHandler"></interceptor-ref>
</interceptor-stack>
```

Comment: Are you using modified interceptor stack? Have you tried with `redirectAction` result type?

Comment: Yes! I am using modified interceptor stack and I haven't used redirectAction result type.

Comment: Show you interceptor stack. Also try with `redirectAction` result type, because you should use it instead of `redirect` to redirect to some action.

Comment: I have added the stack in the question. I'll also try with type="redirectAction"

Comment: By default S2 i18n interceptor stores locale in session, and since your have some `sessionCheck` interceptor you are probably removing it from session with your code.

Comment: In my code I am not removing anything in sessionCheck interceptor. Is there any way to check or set the locale if removed?

Comment: Put a breakpoint into `I18nInterceptor` debug and see what happens on redirect.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19546961/1654265

Comment: Post the struts config with the redirect

Answer (score 1):

Add `request_locale=<your_language_key>` in your parameters

Comment: I have already added request_locale in the parameter but on result type=redirect the locale is reset i.e. changes to default value.

Comment: keep request_locale as variable in action keep getter and setter and set the value and try

Answer (score 0):

Use redirect-action instead of redirect in action result type because in case of redirect action,control jumps to the different action(in same or other package).

Please refer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19002605/struts-2-3-redirect-vs-redirectaction) for the difference between redirect and redirect type result type.